# Custom Vision ONNX Model No Longer Works with Windows 10 ML Oct 2018 Release

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-custom-vision

After upgrading to the latest Windows 10 Oct 2018 release, the exported Custom Vision ONNX model cannot be loaded by the WinML APIs.

I get the following error:

> Unspecified error
>
> Type Error: Type (map(string,tensor(float))) of output arg (loss) of
>   node (ZipMap) does not match expected type
>   (seq(map(string,tensor(float)))).

The updated WinML APIs only work with ONNX models that are v1.2.  What version is exported by Custom Vision?  Just a guess that version requirements may be the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Custom Vision service was just updated to allow the download of ONNX 1.2 models via the portal.  This solved the issue using the new model version.